# in clojure, split function returns nil instead of nonempty vector

Tags: string, clojure, split

I'm reading a file line by line in clojure. when I apply the split function to a line I get nil instead of a vector. here is the code:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(with-open [rdr (reader "somefile")]
  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
    (split line #"\s+")))
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user> (doseq [n (range 10000)] (* n n))
nil
```

`doseq` only ever returns nil. If you want the result of the operation, you should use `for` or `map` instead. You may need to use `doall` to ensure the input is consumed while the reader is still open.

```
user> (take 10 (for [n (range 10000)] (* n n)))
(0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81)
```

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll try this tomorrow when I get to my computer.